# need little about variable

Tags: php, wordpress, http

I created a  bit of code that just condition checks, like below

```
if ( $pretty_link_url==$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
```

If this condition is true and working, then someone is using their browser with the same URL which is in `"$pretty_link_url"`. `"$pretty_link_url"` is found in the database, and the if condition runs if they match. Now my question is

Is there anyway to get the result where both url from above `$pretty_link_url==$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` the same same as ...

```
$url = "result";
```

I don't know if it possible thankyou

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, could you give an example?

Comment: your question not really clear.. give more example

Comment: are you asking if you can have two conditions in your if statement?

Comment: sorry for my wrong poor english :p

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you please explain more.

Comment: I don't at all mind working with non-native English, I just don't know what you're asking. Could you give an example of what result you're looking for, for a few given inputs? Or maybe some pseudo-code?

Comment: Do you ask whether it is possible that someone changes his referrer? If so, yes, one can change manually his referrer and cheat you.

Comment: i mean like if both $pretty_link_url have same result $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) like example.com and condition true i want to get result example.com in $url = "here result show example.com" variable

Comment: If the condition is true insert as the first statement in `if ... {` $url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want but from your comment I think your looking for:

```
<?PHP
if ( $pretty_link_url == $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
   $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}else{
   $url = ""; // empty or some other value you want to use instead
}
?>
```

Comment: Simpler if he wants just this: $url=$pretty_link_url==$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']:'';

Comment: Yes. Thank you. But I think my solution is more easy for him to understand. At least I hope so.

Comment: thanks all its work when someone coming from browser but if i go directly through 301 link it don't show any think look like now i need to stop wasting my time to fix this "HTTP_REFERER" its don't work many cases i need to find another best solution from where visitors come ... thanks for all great help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess at what exactly you're looking for, but is this it?:

```
$url = '';
if ( $pretty_link_url==$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
    $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```